# Converting DOS ^M char to Unix format failing

Tags: bash, sed

I'm removing DOS ^M characters from some files. If I run this sed line on a single file, it removes the characters as expected:

```
$ sed -i 's/^M//g' somefile.txt
```

However, if I run the same line inside a for loop pulling from a list of files, it does not work:

```
$ for i in `cat list`; do sed -i 's/^M//g' $i; done
```

Note that I can apply other commands instead of sed and they perform as expected on each file in sequence. Also, no errors are thrown (not even a code since `echo $?` returns 0). I've tried quoting $i as well.

As per the suggestion in the comments, I tried dos2unix by doing:

```
$ for i in `cat list`; do dos2unix $i; done
```

but nothing changes. Using dos2unix directly on a single file works fine. If my list files was bad, I would expect there to be at least an error code thrown...

Comment: Nope, that would totally work as written (assuming the for loop works for other commands as you say; details of filenames or formatting of the list file might mess things up, but that wouldn't depend on the command you run on each file). Something else is different.

Comment: I'd change your `for` loop to a `while read` and quote `"$i"` but aside from that it's difficult to guess what's wrong.

Comment: did you copy/paste the the chars `^` and `M`, or actually create a Ctrl-M char in that 2nd case. I'm betting copy/paste. Also, if your files are big, you can speed the substitution up (slightly) but anchoring the match to the end-of-line i.e `sed 's/^M$//'` . Finally, doesn't your system have `dos2unix file`? Good luck.

Comment: No copy paste. I did Ctl-V, Ctl-m. Like I said, the command works fine if I run it outside the for loop. Maybe I've done something creepy in my .bashrc or environment.

Comment: Since the files are on an NFS share, I copied the folder over to be local. This time, dos2unix worked on about half the files, but not the rest. I really want to understand this behavior.

Comment: @shellter It turns out you were right about copy/paste. Even though I had been typing ctl-v, ctl-m part of time (like in vim), I was pasting it in w/ tmux when running the loop. So even though I hadn't copy/pasted it from the browser, I was still not getting the control character.

Comment: What is the SO way regarding questions like this? Should I delete it, or should it be marked as duplicate?

Comment: Compared to the junk that gets posted and answered everyday this is a perfectly acceptable question (IHMO). And you have extended your question with answers to our comments, always the sign of some deserving of help in my book ;-) Feel free to post your comment as an answer and accept it when the time limit expires. Others may register contrary comments. Let the vote count decide ;-) Good luck to all!

Comment: @shellter, I could see keeping this open **if** it were edited enough to no longer bring people in to whom the actual issue is of no interest (and to no longer present misleading content as part of the question). As it is, however, it's simply misleading.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Yes, I agree an good title would better. But I have made a minor study of this on S.O. and there doesn't seem to be much correlation between a good title and a good answers. Because we're using google like searches here on S.O. (searching complete Q&A, not just titles), people seem to find what they need regardless.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy :  I won't be modifying the title. My minor study has included trying to find better titles for questions, but changing this question to 'Bad use of ^M Chars in sed command' or 10000 other ideas, seems just as non-helpful, when people don't know they are having problems with Ctrl-M (just for example). I think labyrinth's working thru the process is a good model for new users. If this closes I totally get it and I have voted to close many, many Qs here, so either way is fine with me. Good luck to all!

Comment: Sure, but *if* someone's searching and they see that title, it might give them the idea that ^Ms could possibly be behind their actual problem. Better than having titles and contents be unrelated and hoping for algorithmic magic to do a better job than human judgement can (and, thus, forcing humans to wade through vast quantities of potentially-unrelated content without high-quality summaries). But, yes, we'll see the community decide.

Comment: @labyrinth : See the trouble you have started ;-) Do you mind changing your title to "Bad use of ^M Chars in sed" ? I think your Q and the A below are worth keeping. Maybe having Charles vote back will stem the tide ;-)

Comment: labyrinth: your title is much better. @CharlesDuffy what do you think?

Comment: Much better; close vote retracted.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of `xargs` or `perl -pi -e 's/.../.../g' *`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Even if it was a simple mistake, your comments helped me work through this more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I was I wasn't being careful enough with entering the ^M character when running the commands. As other posts on SO explain, it is necessary to type ctrl-v, ctrl-m to enter ^M as a single control character.

My issue was that I assumed that if I entered it that way initially, it was fine to highlight and paste it after that, but this isn't true for the terminal emulators I'm using (guake, tmux).

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't think that `sed` understands `^M` for carriage return. It should be `\r` instead.

Further, because filenames in UNIX can contain the default field delimiter of bash I suggest to use a while-read loop instead:

```
while read -r file ; do
    sed -i 's/\r//' "$file"
done < list
```

The above loop reads *line-by-line*. However, since files can also contain the new line character itself, mostly it is better to use `find` to generate the list dynamically and use it's `-exec` option:

```
find PATH_TO_FILES -type f -name 'NAME' ... -exec sed -i 's/\r//' {} \;
```

Btw, the `g` option makes no sense in the sed command since the `\r` will only appear once per line. That's why I've omitted it.

Comment: The `^M` that `sed` does understand is a single character, created in most unix environments by escaping with ^V, i.e. press `Ctrl-V` then press `Ctrl-M`. This will display as `^M` and is different than 2 separate chars typed as `^` and `M`. There are a few unix utils that do understand the 2 char `^M` to be `Ctrl-M`, `stty` (I think) being the most common.

Comment: The question looked like it was typed literally as `^`, `M`. Probably that's the root cause? ;)

Comment: In the comments, the O.P. indicates his awareness and use of ctrl-v, ctrl-m, but then later realized that he hadn't been consistent, and had used copy/paste when creating the for loop. My comment to your excellent answer is to set the record straight on `^` `M` vs `^M` ; -)